# Quick'n'dirty way to prototype some serialization in C++?

Tags: c++, serialization

I need to do a prototype that involves some serialization in C++.  It is a quick'n'dirty prototype, so I don't need to solve the problem generally, provide good error checking, or anything like that.  But at the same time, I do need to be able to serialize strings of arbitrary length and with arbitrary charcters.

Are there some best practices for how to whip up a quick data serialization in C++?  Normally I'd just have output records into a text file with one record per line, but my strings may have new lines in them.

Comment: You want to serialize a string? To binary representation or what? Your goal is not clear (since normally serialization refers to objects into xml/binary/etc)

Comment: Are you extremely concerned by CPU speed (e.g. because you have many gigabytes of data to serialize in a few dozens of seconds), or does coding facility matters much more? In the last case, I do recommend JSON.

Comment: You can use an escape character to represent newlines (and other characters) in strings.

Comment: @AlexandreC: you are in principle right, but Json does that already, and have already defined the gory details, and is able to serialize more "structured" data than just arbitrary strings.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, not concerned with perf.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin, it's mostly scalar data, not an object graph.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [JSON](http://json.org/), notably thru [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/). You could also use [libs11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/), a full fledged, template friendly, C++ serialization framework.
(If you want a C library for Json, consider [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/)).

You might also consider using old [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) or [ASN1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asn1) technology.

For a quick & dirty prototype, I do recommend the `JsonCpp` library mentioned above. And using JSON in that case is useful, since it is a textual, nearly-human-friendly, format.

Later you could even perhaps consider going to [MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org) which has a Json-like model.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout serialization with boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Not dirty at all but definitely quick.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind binary data, for each string dump a length (cast to a char*) and then the value of the string to file. It is very easy to read back. POD structs can also be dumped directly by casting to a char*